# Cannot get SilverStripe site working on Amazon Linux 2 Server?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to get this website online, mainly for my own intellectual curiosity (CS student) but also for functional use. The site is built on SilverStripe 4 and developed on a LAMP stack environment.

I have the final SilverStripe site working on my local machine (docker environment using the brettt89/silverstripe-web:7.4-apache image), with another container running MySQL for the database.

I'm using AWS EC2 and followed the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/TUT_WebAppWithRDS.html) on setting up a LAMP stack which included selecting the Amazon Linux 2 Image. I have a single EC2 and RDS running within a VPC that is configured correctly (a test PHP script was able to connect to the db server, query and insert data). In the spirit of incrementally getting things to work, I installed Composer on the EC2 and the PHP extensions listed on SilverStripe's documentation as required. I then ran a `composer create-project silverstripe/installer my-project` and created an ENV file that is the same as my docker environment (still in dev mode) but with the specified endpoint for the db given by the RDS management console.

I also changed the web root of the Apache server to the public subfolder of my site which is: /var/www/html/my-project/public

Note: I also ran the website before changing the webroot and the result was the same.

The site unfortunately returns a server error (HTTP error 500) and the error logs give me some cryptic looking messages that I have been unable to fix. My own suspicion is that there are some file or directory permissions that have been set wrong, so I will share a screenshot.

[File permissions of web directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuSTo.jpg)

Not sure if this helps, but from /etc/httpd/logs/error_log:

```
[Sun Sep 18 03:10:01.441647 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 13852:tid 139677397750336] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Sep 18 03:10:01.441731 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 13852:tid 139677397750336] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Sep 18 03:10:01.443062 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13852:tid 139677397750336] AH00489: Apache/2.4.54 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 18 03:10:01.443080 2022] [core:notice] [pid 13852:tid 139677397750336] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: What about the SilverStripe log?

Comment: @Joundill Is their a separate log for SS errors on server? There is no webpage log showing at all.

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/debugging/error_handling/

Comment: @Joundill The framework is not producing any errors, so logging the same errors (which are non-existent) to a file, isn't going to work.